# GCD of all six digit numbers formed using the digits $1,2,3,4,5,6$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Consider all six digit numbers formed using all the digits $1,2,3,4,5,6$. What is the gcd of these numbers?

Tried it by using combinations, but it is not enough. I don't know the answer, is the gcd $1$?

Comment: A useful fact: if a number has the sum of its digits divisible by $3$, then the number is divisible by $3$.

Comment: $111121$ is prime. I guess the question is a bit unclear.

Comment: We can use every digit exactly once.

Answer (score 5):

Note: a number is a multiple of $3$ (resp. $9$) if and only if the sum of its digits is a multiple of $3$ (resp. $9$).

The GCD of $123456$ and $123465$ divides the difference, which is $9$. So it's $1$, $3$ or $9$. And $1+2+3+4+5+6=21$ is a multiple of $3$, but not a multiple of $9$, so the GCD of all your numbers is $3$.

---

To see why the first sentence is true, write the number in base $10$: $n=d_nd_{n-1}\dots d_0$ (where $d_i$ are the digits).

That is

$$n=\sum_{i=0}^n d_i 10^i$$

Now you don't change the remainder modulo $3$ or $9$ by subtracting a multiple of $9$. And $10^i=9\dots9+1$ is a multiple of $9$ plus $1$, hence the remainder of $n$ modulo $9$ is equal to the remainder modulo $9$ of $\sum_{i=0}^n d_i$.

Comment: You should begin your explanation by the argument given by @eatfood.